# Why does Excel allow me to select the same cell multiple times?

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection, cells

I was selecting cells in Excel, and accidentally selected a cell twice. With a cell selected twice I am no longer able to copy the selection, and I have to cancel the selection and do it again.

Why does Excel allow me to select the same cell multiple times?

Comment: Doing what? Were you entering things into a formula?

Comment: I spoke in formulas? I'm talking about select cells, click in A1, press ctrl and click C2, press ctrl and click again on A1.

Comment: So you're base question here is how to deselect a cell?

Comment: No, the question is what use the multiple selection

Comment: If I accidentally select twice the same cell, I can not copy the selection, so I got in doubt because it is allowed to select twice the same cell, and the answer is no formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To reproduce:**

1. click-and-drag to select A1 & B2

   [image]
2. hold Ctrl, click A1 (notice the highlighting changes)

   [image]
3. try to copy with Ctrl+C (this error is detailed in [kb100715](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100715))

   [image]

I am not sure exactly WHY that happens, but I agree the program seems to believe you are selecting multiple distinct things you hadn't before. [kb2769340](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769340) details this a bit, but highlights on the fact that if you're trying to DESELECT something you already selected (via Ctrl+Click) you have to cancel the selection & start over. [This details a programmable solution to un-select things if you REALLY want to be able to do that](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/374227-highlight-cells-with-ctrl-click-but-only-un-highlight-one-cell.html)

Why do you need this to work, what are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: I did not want to be rude, and researching, it serves no purpose.

Comment: Its okay, I understand frustration! I am confused what you mean by researching serves no purpose? Please upvote or accept an answer to be courteous to people who have tried to help you. If you need anymore help please re-word your question

Comment: This multiple selection, reading what you sent, I realized she has no function. I asked because sometimes when selecionoi many cells end up selecting the same place twice, and must start the selection.

Answer (score 3):

You can select a cell multiple times because formulas can take multiple arguments that may have the same selection.

e.g.

```
=SUM(D1,C1,A1)/C1
```

Comment: Dude, you do not understand, I'm not talking about formulas

Comment: Don't be rude, but that's the answer. You can multi-select for formulas. If you do it outside formulas, you hit an error because that's not what it's for.

Comment: I did not want to be rude, and researching, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I can understand your frustration in seeing everyone misunderstand. Microsoft says it's intentional and meant to highlight overlaps when doing multiple selections

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769340

Comment: This duplicates information in the accepted answer.  It is intended that each answer contribute a substantially different solution from what has already been posted.